# How does a broadband dielectric Mirror work?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, quantum-optics, optical-materials

It is widely known that dielectric mirrors work with several layers of at least two materials which differ in refractive index that are layered, such that partially reflected waves interfere constructively. However, in the simple explanation that is usually given (layers of thickness $\lambda/4$, two materials), the resulting mirror is working properly only for exactly one wavelength (or at a specific angle). However, there exist broadband dielectric mirrors, that maintain a very high reflectivity (>99%) over a large range of wavelength (eg from 1300-1900 nm) and in addition  (probably working similarly) there are mirrors working for an AOI of 0-45°. How is this possible, i.e. what is the structure of the layers? (I'm looking for the idea behind it, I guess the exact structure is a rather demanding numerical problem)

Comment: With 100 or more individual layers, high end broadband mirrors have a lot of knobs to turn to try and optimize reflectivity.

Comment: I don't think that it's accurate to say that quarter-wave coatings work properly for exactly one wavelength. [For example](https://www.layertec.de/en/capabilities/coatings/dielectric/): *"The spectral width of the reflection band and the achievable reflectivity for a given number of layer pairs depends on the ratio of the refractive indices of the layer materials. **A large refractive index ratio results in a broad reflection band** while a narrow reflection band can be produced using materials with a low refractive index ratio. "*

Comment: @JonCuster , yes, indeed. But how do we try to optimize reflectivity when turning the knobs?

Comment: @HalHollis I would agree with your reasoning for one layer only. There the large ratio results in a broad reflection band. However, the condition that all partially reflected waves have to constructively interfere is (for a fixed angle) still only fulfilled for one wavelength, right?

Comment: https://www.rp-photonics.com/dielectric_mirrors.html gives a broad overview, and they will be happy to sell you their software (https://www.rp-photonics.com/coating.html). How to turn the knobs is mostly a software/algorithm issue of finding a desired response out of $n$ layers.

Comment: Simon, if the constructive interference isn't perfect, it doesn't follow that the reflectivity isn't greater than some minimum desired value. [For example](https://lightmachinery.com/optical-design-center/thin-film-cloud/?key=7OA9VubJIUaqY_IELGEDGw), a coating with 25 QW (@ 1600 nm) doublets of SiO2 and Ta2O5 is HR over the band from 1430 nm to 1820 nm. I'm sure there are techniques to widen this but the point I'm making is that an HR QW mirror isn't necessarily narrow band.